# Google Sheets API Node Client Library Minimal Example

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to follow [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) guide, however although I am the owner of a GCP project, I cannot click the button in Step 1, because that behaviour has been disabled by my employer. There are no alternative instructions to follow in this case. I have tried to assume what actions the button would have taken as: enable the Google Sheets API, then create and download client credentials and save as `credentials.json`.

However on line 43 of the [code given in step 3](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/node-samples/blob/master/sheets/quickstart/index.js) credentials.installed is called, however the client credentials I created for my GCP project has no "installed" key. I would like detailed instructions of how to create the correct `credentials.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

### This is what a credentials.json file needs to look like:

```
{"installed":{"client_id":"XXX","project_id":"XXX","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"XXX","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}
```

Please replace the `XXX` for the `client_id`, `project_id` and `Client secret` with your data.

If you are able to access the [API console](https://console.developers.google.com/), you should be able to retrieve those credentials there, otherwise ask you Admin to do it for you.